# Combine one-to-one and many-to-many (django)

Tags: django, design-patterns, many-to-many, api-design

I have a model named "db_connector" and another one "project_site".

---

A "project_site" can have many to many relation with "db-connector".
But the "project_site" should have one default db-connector.

---

What is the best design-pattern for this?
*Can I combine many to many  and one to one like this*:
Many to many relation for *alternative connectors* linked to a project_site and one to one for the default connector linked to a project_site?

The user can specify a db_connector, if the user doesn't specify a database_conector, the default db_connector can be used?

---

Using this pattern on django causes an error (fields.E305)

> Project_site.alternative_db_connectors: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Project_site.alternative_db_connectors' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project_site.default_db_connector'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Project_site.alternative_db_connectors' or 'Project_site.default_db_connector'.

The project_site models looks like this:

```
class Project_site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    project_group = models.ForeignKey(Project_Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    default_db_connector = models.OneToOneField(DB_Connector, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,  primary_key=True ,)
    alternative_db_connectors = models.ManyToManyField(DB_Connector)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

In SQL terms it should be possible, right?

Comment: Is the default one-to-one because only one connector can be a default at a time?

Comment: Is there logic which one will be the default, or should it be stored per connection separately without logic determining which one is the default?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the one-to-one connector is the default connector the many-to-many should contain the alternative connectors. The users can ask for a different connector, which is the same model as the default connector.

Comment: @bdbd yes exactly

Comment: In that case then yes, IMO it should be fine to have a one-to-one FK for the default (knowing a connector can be the default of just one project a time) and another m2m FK for the alternatives

Comment: @bdbd the problem is it causes an error on django, (fields.E305) :  Reverse query name for 'Project_site.alternative_db_connectors' clashes with reverse query name for 'Project_site.default_db_connector'.

Comment: Just use unique related names

Comment: For the default, something like: `default_db_connector = models.ForeignKey(related_name='project_default')`

Comment: For the alternative: `alternative_db_connectors = models.ManyToMany(related_name='project_alternative')`

Comment: @bdbd Thank you for you help ;)

Comment: No worries. Just make sure you read about [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to understand how it works